# How do I avoid LNK2005 and LNK1169 errors while compiling TetGen in my project?

Tags: c++, header-files, tetrahedra, tetgen

I am trying to compile TetGen and use the code below to tetrahedralize a .ply file although I am getting these two linker errors:

**LNK2005 main already defined in tetgen.obj**

**LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found**

The files that are includes in my project solution are **"tetgen.h"**, **"predicates.cxx"**, and **"tetgen.cxx"**, and the folder path that these three files are in is included in my Project **Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories**. I did the same for the "monkey.ply" file as well.

This is all the code in my main file:

```
#include "tetgen.h"

int main()
{
    tetgenio in, out;
    in.firstnumber = 0;
    in.load_ply((char *)"monkey.ply");
    tetgenbehavior* b = new tetgenbehavior();
    tetrahedralize(b, &in, &out);
}
```

Here are the "tetgen.h", "predicates.cxx", and "tetgen.cxx" files I'm using : https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home?url=https://github.com/libigl/tetgen

I researched these errors and looked around a great amount but can't see why this is occurring. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may have this issue in the future with TetGen: The problem was that the TETGEN_LIBRARY flag needed to be defined in tetgen.h. I knew this, but every time I defined the flag, it would cause memory errors without fail. So, I kept TETGEN_LIBRARY undefined to avoid the memory error. Turns out, with TETGEN_LIBRARY defined, it will work. The problem was that "monkey.ply" did not exist/was in the wrong folder. Because "monkey.ply" did not exist it threw an unhandled exception. Why TetGen does not have a simple handle to check if a file exists before it tries to load it or not is beyond me. But that fixed things.

Answer (score 0):

> LNK2005 main already defined in tetgen.obj

This message tries to tell you that your tetgen library contains the `main` function. Your "main file" also contains a `main` function. This is a conflict. You should remove your `main` function from your code, and read the documentation of the tetgen library on how to provide a replacement. Typically, libraries which define their own `main` functions require you to rename your `main` to have some other name, which the documentation should clearly specify.

```
#include "tetgen.h"

int main_replacement_called_by_tetgen()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I will look for something like that in the documentation. I was not aware of that practice, thank you so much!